# Python, change current shell environment variables while using Popen?

Tags: python

I have an XML that contains information about environment variable to set into the shell by my python script.  Here is a snippet of the XML :

```
<envVar name='QTDIR'>/homeqt/libs.qt4/qt4.5.1</envVar>
<envVar name='MAKE'>which make</envVar>
```

This part of this snippet tells my python script to set environment variables QTDIR and MAKE.

My concern is the difference how i have to set the above variables.  I know that i can use os.environ to set environment variables and do something like this :

```
os.environ['QTDIR'] = "/homeqt/libs.qt4/qt4.5.1"
```

But i can't use this to set my MAKE variable, i have to execute the command "*which make*" (to get the path of make executable).  My goal is to use the same method/function to set every variables.

SO, i thought to do something like this:

```
Popen("QTDIR=/homeqt/libs.qt4/qt4.5.1 ; export QTDIR", shell=True, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
Popen("MAKE=which make ; export MAKE", shell=True, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
```

But if i do this, the variable will be set only for the subprocess, not for the current shell.

So, my question is, is there a way to do what i want?  I DON'T want to analyse the XML and do something like this :

(pseudocode)

```
if QTDIR has normal value
    os.environ['QTDIR'] = "/homeqt/libs.qt4/qt4.5.1"
if MAKE has value to be executed
    p = Popen("which make", shell=True, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
    stdout, stderr = p.communicate()
    os.environ['MAKE'] = stdout
```

Comment: We have quite complex bash shell scripts with tons of if then else to build our products.  I want to move much information as possible inside the XML and make the python script just calls jobs extracted from it.  I want the python script simple as possible.  That is why.  So, is it possible?

Comment: @peterphonic So, you want to have some values that have to be handled specially, but you're not willing to handle them specially anywhere?

Comment: Yeah, somthing like this =)  I think the solution below makes more sense...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would make use of XML attributes.

```
<envVar name="MAKE" type="command">which make</envVar>
<envVar name="QTDIR" type="string">/homeqt/libs.qt4/qt4.5.1</envVar>
```

pseudocode depending on your xml library:

```
if node.attributes['type'] == 'command':
    value = os.popen(node.firstChild.text).read()
elif node.attributes['type'] == 'string':
    value = node.firstChild.text
os.environ[node.attributes['name']] = value
```

Comment: Good answer! Even better, upgrade to the `subprocess.check_output()` Standard Library method that Nick Coghlan has been advocating because of its better design.

Comment: I just messed around with this, and I agree that this is a better solution for some situations, but probably not this one. This would require you to parse the command yourself, as check_output takes in an array of arguments, so you might have to try something like check_output(command.split(' ')), which is just bad news and won't do the right thing in nearly all of the cases (what if I have quoted strings, escaped spaces, or semicolons without spaces next to them?) Better to pass it to the shell's grammar parser.

Comment: Just pass `shell=True` to the function: `check_output(command, shell=True)`

Comment: Ah. This argument is not documented in its help page :(

Comment: Indeed — consider filing a bug so they can update the docstring to match the great work that Nick has been doing in the Standard Library documentation, where he has both moved the convenience calls like `check_output()` to the top, and also made clear that they take arguments like `shell`: http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html

Comment: @stefan: `os.popen().read()` doesn't distinguish between an error and empty output.

Answer (score 0):

Your representation is ambiguous:

```
<envVar name='QTDIR'>/homeqt/libs.qt4/qt4.5.1</envVar>
<envVar name='MAKE'>which make</envVar>
```

How do you decide between `MAKE=which make` or `` MAKE=`which make` ``:

```
$ a=which make ; echo $a
make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.

$ a=`which make` ; echo $a
/usr/bin/make

$ a='which make' ; echo $a
which make
```

If the xml file is machine generated and humans don't view/edit this file often then you could use a verbose explicit notation such as [suggested by @stefan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8101641/python-change-current-shell-environment-variables-while-using-popen/8101787#8101787).

Otherwise a more succinct and simple representation might be used:

```
QTDIR: /homeqt/libs.qt4/qt4.5.1
$MAKE: which make
```

Here's a Python script that parses that format into a dictionary:

```
for line in file:
    name, sep, value = map(str.strip, line.partition(':'))
    if sep: # ':' is in the line           
       if name.startswith('$'):
          name = name[1:] # strip '$'
          value = subprocess.check_output(value, shell=True).strip()
       d[name] = value
```

Or you could do e.g.:

```
d = yaml.load(file) # yaml is as complex as xml, but less explicit i.e., worse
# and transform keys that start with '$' here
```

xml format could be a justified fallback if you need more complex capabilities.

Comment: Actually, i think XML is a better solution.  It does not only contain information about variables, but also jobs that has to be executed :    <job tag='Create_Directories'>
    cd $MAINPATH; 
    mkdir -p $TARGET; 
    cd "$MAINPATH/$TARGET"; 
    rm -rf $VARIANT
   </job>

Comment: @peterphonic: In this case a db such as sqlite could more appropriate to keep track of job states.